# Evaluate the Integral $\int_{C} (z-z_0)^n dz$ where $C$ be the line segment from $z_0+r-ir$ to $z_0+r+ir$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $z_0 \in \mathbb{C}$ , $r>0$,

Let $C$ be the line segment from $z_0+r-ir$ to $z_0+r+ir$.

A parametrization of the smooth curve $C$ is

$z(t) = z_0 + r + i(2rt-r)$, $t\in[0,1]$

and $z'(t)=2ri$.

Then, $\int_{C} (z-z_0)^n dz = \int_{0}^{1} [r+i(2rt-r)]^n  2r$ $dt$. $(n\in \mathbb{Z})$

I need help on further evaluating the integral. (for $n\neq -1$ and $n=-1$)

Comment: $z'(t)=2ir{}{}$

Comment: pull out $r$ and let $1+i(2t-1)=u$

Comment: So much sloppiness in this... The phrase "polygonal line" is distracting when one only has a **segment**, the case to be treated separately is $n=-1$, not $n=1$ (and one can find distressing that two answerers do not correct this but, for no apparent reason, limit themselves to $n$ nonnegative), some factor $i$ disappears, you do not say why finding an antiderivative of a **polynomial** function is a problem at all... and so on.

Answer (score 0):

For $n\in \mathbb{N}$
$$\int_{C} (z-z_0)^n dz = \int_{0}^{1} r^n[1+i(2t-1)]^n  2ridt$$
Now let $1+i(2t-1)=u$ then $2idt=du$ and
\begin{align}
\int_{C} (z-z_0)^n dz 
&= r^{n+1}\int_{1-i}^{1+i} u^n du \\
&= r^{n+1}\dfrac{(1+i)^{n+1}-(1-i)^{n+1}}{n+1} \\
&= \dfrac{2i}{n+1}(r\sqrt{2})^{n+1}\sin\dfrac{\pi(n+1)}{4}
\end{align}